# woocommerce price filter widget

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I haven't been able to fix the WooCommerce price filter problem for about 10 days.
I designed a WordPress template and then converted it to a store using WooCommerce functions. Everything is correct except for the filters and among all the WooCommerce filters the price filter.
Either it doesn't appear at all, or if it does, it doesn't work and it doesn't have a slider.
Please advise how can I fix this problem?
[image]